# Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'. setting up a Twitter login for website

Tags: vb.net, twitter, authentication, web, webforms

Hi I am using Visual studio ultimate 2012 VB.NET

I am trying to set up a new part of my website using Visual studio web forms. I want users to be able to login using there Twitter id. So I created my Twitter login app and inserted my 2 keys "Consumer key" & "Consumer secret" key in to my "AuthConfig.vb" file

I then setup my database using Visual studios "Connect to Database" It connected to my database successfully. I know this because after a message popped up telling me "connection was successful". I was then able on to use visual studio to setup a table on my database.
I confirmed the table was created by logging in to my GoDaddy server and checking the database table was showing, and it was. (So this confirms VS can connect to database.

So this is what happens,
I go to my new page I just created in VS which is this one
http://mastersworldofcomputing.com/basic-learning/Default.aspx

I then click on "Log in" which takes me to this page below.
http://mastersworldofcomputing.com/basic-learning/Account/Login.aspx

I then click on the "Twitter button" we just created (which should let me log in with Twitter id)
I am then taken to the Twitter login page, so I put username and password in and click on "Sign in".
I then get a flash screen come up telling me it is redirecting me to my page but after a couple of seconds it takes me to an error page. Showing info below.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

Source Error:


Line 90:         ' User has logged in with provider successfully
Line 91:         ' Check if user is already registered locally
Line 92:         If OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie:=False) Then
Line 93:             RedirectToReturnUrl()
Line 94:         End If


Source File: D:\hosting\7560507\html\basic-learning\Account\RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.vb    Line: 92
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup) +907262
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +4116
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
           System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +122
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +131
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +332
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63  
Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.GetMembershipUserName(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean updateLastUsed) +891
Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthManager.Login(HttpContextBase context, String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +105
Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.Login(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +95
Account_RegisterExternalLogin.ProcessProviderResult() in D:\hosting\7560507\html\basic-learning\Account\RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.vb:92
Account_RegisterExternalLogin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\hosting\7560507\html\basic-learning\Account\RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.vb:48
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

**My web.config file look like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebSite17-20121215190635;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebSite17-20121215190635.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </profile>
  <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
 </roleManager>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
<entityFramework>.

<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
 </defaultConnectionFactory>
 </entityFramework>
 </configuration>
```

Is there anyone who can put me on the right track here so I can get past this. I must of read a hundred threads and got no where. If there is some other info that might be of use let me know
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not sure, so I post it as a comment, but I think the `Initial Catalog` or the `AttachDbFileName` entries in your connection string are mutually exclusive. Have you tried to remove the Initial Catalog part from the connection string?